# I need to get the latitude and longitude of my marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It is a simple map that focuses according to the name of the city, and you can place a marker to indicate where you live. The idea is to save the longitude and latitude in a database, but first I need to get it.

So far I have the code:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.775, -122.4183333);
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 3,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var pais = 'Argentina'; 
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': pais}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);


        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<div style='font-size: 8pt; font-family: verdana ;' >Mi marca situada en<br></div>"
            });    

        var marker; 
        function placeMarker(location) {
            if ( marker ) {
                marker.setPosition(location);

            } else {
                var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: 'hola',
                });
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            infoWindow.open(map,marker);
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    });
```

I have tried with various methods but not get good results. I want to do with gmaps api v3.
Here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz56ywej/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Radu said, mostly.  I was [updating your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz56ywej/4/) at the same time he was it seems.  Additionally, you might find it more convenient to wait until you have that latLng before you construct your infoWindow object, like this:

```
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div class='infoWindow'>Mi marca situada en<br>"
        + "Lat: " + event.latLng.lat() + "<br>"
        + "Lng: " + event.latLng.lng() + "</div>"
    });
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

If you want to update the contents of your infoWindow, use `infoWindow.setContent()`.

See the [Google Maps API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for an exhaustive list of objects and their properties.

Comment: `latLng.k`,`latLng.B` are undocumented properties of the latLng object, they can and will change with new releases.  Do not use them, use the documented .lat() and .lng() functions.

Comment: All right! it works :) Just one thing: For every click a new marker is created but the previous stays behind and stacked. No way that does not happen?

Comment: @nicogaldo Yes, there is a way.  Instead of declaring "var infoWindow" within the click event callback, declare it in the global scope.  Then check whether infoWindow already exists before creating a new one.  I [updated my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz56ywej/4/) to illustrate.  Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Uff.. when you place the marker you already have it's position. This `position: location` contains the position of your marker.
In case you somehow need that position you can access it through there or you can do `marker.getPosition()`.

I've updated your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jz56ywej/1/).

Note: 'k' is lowercase, 'A' is uppercase - in the getPosition() returned object.

Comment: `getPosition().k`,`getPosition().A` are undocumented properties of the latLng object, they can and will change with new releases.  Do not use them, use the documented .lat() and .lng() functions.